# Check if App.config is well configured

Tags: error, web-config, database-connection

I want to connect to sql DB, and I have in my Sharepoint project an App.config (with properties : Build "None", Copy to Output directory"Copy always"), I added a reference to System.Configuration.dll (Version 2), and my app.config is like that :

```
<connectionStrings>   
    <add name="ExchangeRate" connectionString="Data Source=CH-SQL;Initial Catalog=COMMON;User ID=_cb;Password=***" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I call the connection string in my code :

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
...
 exchangeRate = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExchangeRate"].ConnectionString;
```

in my project.exe.config , I can see connectionString

I have the following error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Maybe my app.config is not working correctly

Help please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how you define your connection in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyConnectionString" 
         connectionString ="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PUBS.MDF; 
                            Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

And to use the connection string, use the below code.

```
private SqlConnection con = null;
con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it still same error , PS : when I use a string instead of connectionString it connects me

Comment: Are you able to connect with DB now ?

Comment: When I put string (and not read from app.config) I am able : `string connstr = "Data Source=CH-SQLD;Initial Catalog=LOGS;User ID=***;Password=***";
 DataProviderUtility.ExecuteStoredProcedureToSqlDatabase(sqlParam, StoredProcedures.CREATELOG, connstr)`

Comment: Have you added this connection string in STS and Central admin web.config file as well, if not pls try that

Comment: could you please give me further details, sorry for the dumb questions : what's STS? I cannot find web.config (it's a solution developed by another person, I am just making few changes)

Comment: Security Token service, found under SharePoint Web Services in IIS

Comment: thank youuuuu, it works, I don't find your solution in another same issue, thank you again :)

Comment: Glad that helped :)